# VBA: How to delete rows and keep some rows based on criteria?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been writing this macro which has three steps to it. ***First*** is to delete rows if rows are blank after Column **C** and the ***Second*** step is there are rows with titles that have to remain in the workbook like **Contributions-All Other** or **Program Fees-Youth**. The ***Third*** step is to format the row by adding spaces or empty rows after certain titles.

This my code and it doesn't seem to compile and I am not sure how prevent rows from deleting...please help.

```
Sub RemoveRowsAndFormat()  
 Dim WS As Worksheet
 For Each WS In Sheets
 WS.Activate


   Dim n As Long
     Dim nlast As Long
     Dim rw As Range
     Set rw = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
     nlast = rw.Count
     For n = nlast To 9 Step -1
      If (rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Contributions-All Other" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Program Fees - Youth" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Financial Assitance" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Salaries & Wages" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Payroll Taxes" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Employee Benefits" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Staff Training and Confer." Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Occupancy" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Supplies" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Telephone" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Postage & Shipping" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Promotion and Advertising" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Bad Debt" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Program Operating Expense" Or rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Program Operating Net") Then
      rw.Rows(n).EntireRow.Insert
        ElseIf (rw.Cells(n, 4).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 5).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 6).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 7).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 8).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 9).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 10).Value = "" And rw.Cells(n, 11).Value = "") Then
             rw.Rows(n).Delete


         End If

     Next n
     Next WS
 End Sub
```

Comment: First off, `rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Contributions-All Other" And rw.Cells(n, 3).Value = "Program Fees - Youth"` is going to evaluate to `False` - `rw.Cells(n, 3).Value` cannot be equal to `"Contributions-All Other"` **AND** be equal to `"Program Fees - Youth"`.  You need to use `Or` rather than `And`.

Comment: And I suggest that `Set rw = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows` should probably just be `Set rw = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange`.

Comment: Apart from those comments, can you tell us what error message you are getting - that will allow us to get to the cause of your compile error.

Comment: After applying those fixes the code is complying, the issue is NOT all of the titles need spacing. The ones in the first `if` statement they just need to stay and not be deleted but some do need spacing and how do I insert a row under the titles? @YowE3K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your (edited) question seems to be doing what you want, except that it is adding a row **above** your headings instead of **below** it.  That could be fixed by changing `rw.Rows(n).EntireRow.Insert` to `rw.Rows(n + 1).EntireRow.Insert` but that could lead to problems (if a heading exists on the last row) due to the way you have defined `rw`.

I have refactored your code to use a `Select Case` statement to replace your (IMO) unwieldy `If` statement, and to refer to the worksheet rather than just certain rows when deciding where to perform insertions/deletions.

```
Sub RemoveRowsAndFormat()  
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim n As Long
    Dim nlast As Long
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim c As Long
    Dim allEmpty As Boolean
    For Each WS In Worksheets
        With WS
            nlast = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
            For n = nlast To 9 Step -1
                Select Case .Cells(n, 3).Value 

                    Case "Contributions-All Other", _
                         "Program Fees - Youth", _
                         "Financial Assitance", _
                         "Salaries & Wages", _
                         "Payroll Taxes", _
                         "Employee Benefits", _
                         "Staff Training and Confer.", _
                         "Occupancy", _
                         "Supplies", _
                         "Telephone", _
                         "Postage & Shipping", _
                         "Promotion and Advertising", _
                         "Bad Debt", _
                         "Program Operating Expense", _
                         "Program Operating Net"

                        .Rows(n + 1).EntireRow.Insert

                    Case Else

                        allEmpty = True
                        For c = 4 To 11
                            If .Cells(n, c).Value <> "" Then
                                allEmpty = False
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                        'The above could be replaced by a "COUNTA", but I like this way
                        If allEmpty Then
                            .Rows(n).Delete
                        End If
                End Select
            Next n
        End With
    Next WS
End Sub
```

---

You say in a recent comment that a new issue "is NOT all of the titles need spacing".  If so, the `Select Case` statement makes it easy to include that functionality as follows:

```
                Select Case .Cells(n, 3).Value 

                    'Do nothing for headings which we just want to leave alone
                    Case "Contributions-All Other", _
                         "Program Fees - Youth", _
                         "Financial Assitance", _
                         "Salaries & Wages", _
                         "Payroll Taxes", _
                         "Employee Benefits", _
                         "Staff Training and Confer.", _
                         "Occupancy", _
                         "Supplies"

                    'Process cases where an additional row needs to be inserted
                    Case "Telephone", _
                         "Postage & Shipping", _
                         "Promotion and Advertising", _
                         "Bad Debt", _
                         "Program Operating Expense", _
                         "Program Operating Net"

                        .Rows(n + 1).EntireRow.Insert

                    'For all the other rows, check whether it needs to be deleted
                    Case Else

                        allEmpty = True
                        '...
```

(Obviously, I have just made up which headings should have rows inserted after them and which shouldn't.)

That `Select Case` statement is just a simplified(?) way of writing the following `If` statement:

```
If .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Contributions-All Other" Or _
   .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Program Fees - Youth" Or _
   .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Financial Assitance" Or _
   .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Salaries & Wages" Or _
   .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Payroll Taxes" Or _
   .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Employee Benefits" Or _
   .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Staff Training and Confer." Or _
   .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Occupancy" Or _
   .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Supplies" Then

ElseIf .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Telephone" Or _
       .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Postage & Shipping" Or _
       .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Promotion and Advertising" Or _
       .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Bad Debt" Or _
       .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Program Operating Expense" Or _
       .Cells(n, 3).Value = "Program Operating Net" Then

    .Rows(n + 1).EntireRow.Insert

Else

    allEmpty = True
    '...
End If
```

---

P.S.  Should "Financial Assitance" be "Financial Assistance"?

Comment: Do the cases have to be in order?

Comment: @MTBthePRO - What do you mean "in order"?  It will execute the statements of the first `Case` that evaluates to `True` so from that perspective they need to be in the order in which you want the statements to be checked, but you have three(?) mutually exclusive events so it doesn't really matter for you (other than that `Case Else` needs to come last).

Comment: I figured it out. One of the case statement was missing a comma.

Comment: @MTBthePRO - Was that in my answer, or in your edited version of the answer?  (i.e. Do I need to edit the answer so that it doesn't confuse future readers?)

Comment: No you are fine sir. Thank you for the help. @YowE3K